# An explicit example of the simple approximation lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I just got the Simple Approximation Lemma in the text Real Analysis by Royden, and I was wondering if anyone could provide an *explicit* example of this lemma. Below I will include the Lemma and a function that satisfices the criteria.

**The Simple Approximation Lemma:** Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on a Lebesgue measurable set $E$. If $f$ is bounded on $E$ then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists simple functions
$\phi_{\epsilon}$ and $\psi_{\epsilon}$ on $E$ such that:

$\phi_{\epsilon}(x) \leq f(x) \leq \psi_{\epsilon}(x), \forall x \in E \tag{1}$

$0 \leq \psi_{\epsilon}(x) - \phi_{\epsilon}(x) < \epsilon \tag{2}$

So, the function $f: [0, 2\pi]\to[-1, 1]$ defined by $f(x) = \sin{x}$ is a Lebesgue measurable function on a Lebesgue measurable set, and is bounded, namely by the following $|f(x)| \leq 1$, hence, the Simple Approximation Lemma applies (Right?). Can anyone give *explicit* examples of the simple functions $\phi_{\epsilon}$ and $\psi_{\epsilon}$?

My attempt was to use the fact that $|f(x)| \leq 1$. So, I tried the following simple functions:

$\psi_{\epsilon} = 1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{i}$

$\phi_{\epsilon} = -1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\tag{ii}$

However, property (2) of the Simple Approximation Lemma fails since

$\psi_{\epsilon} - \phi_{\epsilon} = 2 - \epsilon.$

Comment: What's your guess about $\phi_{\epsilon}$ and $\psi_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: @FormulaWriter I will go ahead and include my attempt, though it does not work.

Comment: In case you got stuck, it may probably be useful following the construction in Royden proof of the lemma.

Comment: @FormulaWriter I suppose, I just figured it would be *easier* than that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. We will focus on the interval $[0,\pi]$. For $ 0 \leq k \leq n-1$ . consider the the sets $E_k = emf^{-1}\mid_{[0,\pi]}((\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}])$.

Now define the function $\phi$ and $\psi$ as follows :

$$ \phi =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n} \times \chi_{E_{k}} \hspace{0.2 cm} \phi(0)= \phi(\pi) = 0 \\
\psi = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k+1}{n} \times \chi_{E_{k}} \hspace{0.2 cm} \psi(0) = \psi(1) = 0$$

For every $x \in [0,\pi]$ we have $\phi(x) \leq f(x) \leq \psi(x)$ and $0 \leq \psi(x) - \phi(x) \leq \epsilon.$

**Note**: For a subset of $E$ of the above interval. $\chi_{E}$ is the characteristic function of that subset.

And this method could easily be extended to the whole interval $[0,2\pi]$.